# Avoiding time consuming logic when using flatmapIterable

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a task to split a word into characters and then transfer each to another word.

I write some test code, use **toCharArray** to get char array in the **flatMapIterable** section, but if the target string is a bigger one, I think this method is time-consuming and sync.

My question is there is have better way or alternative to do this in reactor style and avoid time-consuming?

```
   final String s = "acebo";
        Mono.just(s)
                .log()
                .flatMapIterable(str -> {
                    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
                    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (char aChar : chars) {
                        result.add(String.valueOf(aChar));
                    }
                    return result;
                })
                .flatMap(this::retrieveSymbolLetter)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);

    private Mono<String> retrieveSymbolLetter(Object symbol) {
        return Mono.defer(() -> {
            String result;
            switch (symbol.toString()) {
                case "a":
                    result = "aspect";
                    break;
                case "b":
                    result = "bad";
                    break;
                case "c":
                    result = "context";
                    break;
                case "d":
                    result = "dad";
                    break;
                default:
                    result = "default";
                    break;
            }
            return Mono.just(result);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider using such a method:

```
Flux.fromStream(s.chars().mapToObj(str->(char)str).map(String::valueOf));
```

instead of begining of your code:

```
Mono.just(s)
            .log()
            .flatMapIterable ...
```

Answer is based on documentation to Flux:

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#fromStream-java.util.stream.Stream-
I am not sure is a best answer which we could write :)
I assume it's more eficient to create a Flux then converting Mono to Flux via flatMapIterable.